# Algebraic dependence is transitive

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials

Let $p\in \mathbb C[x_1,\dots,x_n]$, and $B,C\subset\mathbb C[x_1,\dots,x_n] $ two subsets. I am trying to show by hand that  if $p$ is algebraic over $B$ and $B$ algebraic over $C$, then $p$ is algebraic over $C$.

Any idea or reference ?

**Edit**. Here *$B$ algebraic over $C$* means that every $b\in B$ is algebraic over some $c_1,\dots,c_n$ in $C$, which means that there are polynomials $Q_0(\bar x),Q_1(\bar x),\dots,Q_m(\bar x)\in \mathbb C[x_1,\dots,x_n]$, such that $Q_1(c_1,\dots,c_n)b+\dots+Q_m(c_1,\dots,c_n)b^m=Q_0(c_1,\dots,c_n)$ and $Q_m(c_1,\dots,c_n)\neq 0$.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “by hand”? Would writing out a proof of the fact qualify?

Comment: I mean using elementary polynomial computations, but any proof would qualify, sure

Comment: Then what are $B$ and $C$? Are they just sets, or are they subrings, or what?

Comment: They are just sets

Comment: What does it mean for an element of a ring $R$ to be algebraic over a subset of $R$? Or for a subset of a ring $R$ to be algebraic over another subset? I'm not familiar with the term "algebraic" being used in such a fashion.

Comment: @Hurkyl: I gave the definition of what I meant in this case, and I guess one could define that $a\in R$ is algebraic over $S\subset R$ if there is a non-trivial polynomial with coefficients in the ring generated by $S$ that vanishes in $a$. But I don't know if this definition is relevant then, i.e. if it is transitive and satisfies the exchange property.

Comment: Well, it’s a standard fact that algebraicness is transitive, when you’re talking about a situation of fields $K\subset E\subset F$ where both $F\supset E$ and $E\supset K$ are algebraic, which implies that $F\supset K$ is algebraic. If you were hoping to start with an equation for $p$ with coefficients in $\Bbb C(B)$ and using the separate equations for each of the coefficients as algebraic over $\Bbb C(C)$, this would be a royal mess, whose messiness and impenetrability would only verify the superiority of the abstract approach.